# How do i send messages to Azure Service Bus after completion of activity in Azure data Factory

Tags: azure, access-token, azureservicebus, azure-data-factory

I am trying to send a message to azure service bus through REST API after an activity is completed in Azure data factory pipeline. But how can i generate access token to send messages inside azure data factory.

Azure data factory has only on web activity through which i can call rest endpoints, Is there a solution possible with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommand that you could use the Azure Httptrigger function to that.

You could implement send message with Azure httptigger function. And Call Http trigger function in the Azure datafactory.

For more information about Azure Httptrigger function, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook).

And then we could use the [Web activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) to call an Azure function endpoint from a Data Factory pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, this way works, but i was wondering if there was a solution which didn't involve azure functions. Just using plain web requests

Comment: Based on my experience, I have no idea to do that just with plain web request currently. But I think Azure function is an easy to do that.

Answer (score 2):

There is two ways to send messages from ADF to a Service Bus.

First, you need to grant the Azure Service Bus data sender role.

[image]

[image]

You can then send messages using a copy activity, which allows you to send an entire data set, or using a web activity, which allows you to send a body or a parameter.

Settings in Linked Service for **Copy Activity**:

[image]

Settings in **Web Activity**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to use the ADF web activity with to interact with the Service Bus REST api directly using the ADF's managed identitity.

It requires granting relevant permission on the Service Bus namespace for the ADF's managed identity (e.g. by assigning the [Azure Service Bus Data Sender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#azure-service-bus-data-sender) role). Rather than generating an access token, you can use the [managed identity authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#managed-identity) option in the web activity and set the resource value as `https://servicebus.azure.net`.

For a worked example please take a look at my [blog post on sending messages to service bus from ADF](https://medium.com/asos-techblog/sending-messages-from-azure-data-factory-to-service-bus-86d4be6dd357).